# Assign variables in groups based on fractions and several conditions

Tags: r, grouping, fractions

I've tried for several days on something I think should be rather simple, with no luck. Hope someone can help me!

I have a data frame called "test" with the following variables: "Firm", "Year", "Firm_size" and "Expenditures".

I want to assign firms to size groups by year and then display the mean, median, std.dev and N of expenditures for these groups in a table (e.g. stargazer). So the first size group (top 10% largest firms) should show the mean, median ++ of expenditures for the 10% largest firms each year.

The size groups should be,

- The 10% largest firms
- The firms that are between 10-25% largest
- The firms that are between 25-50% largest
- The firms that are between 50-75% largest
- The firms that are between 75-90% largest
- The 10% smallest firms

This is what I have tried:

```
test<-arrange(test, -Firm_size)
test$Variable = 0
test[1:min(5715, nrow(test)),]$Variable <- "Expenditures, 0% size <10%"
test[5715:min(14288, nrow(test)),]$Variable <- "Expenditures, 10% size <25%"
test[14288:min(28577, nrow(test)),]$Variable <- "Expenditures, 25% size <50%"
--> And so on


library(dplyr)
testtest = test%>%
 group_by(Variable)%>%
  dplyr::summarise(
    Mean=mean(Expenditures),
    Median=median(Expenditures),
    Std.dev=sd(Expenditures),
    N=n()
  )

stargazer(testtest, type = "text", title = "Expenditures firms", digits = 1, summary = FALSE)
```

As shown over, I dont know how I could use fractions/group by percentage. I have therefore tried to assign firms in groups based on their rows after having arranged Firm_size to descending. The problem with doing so is that I dont take year in to consideration which I need to, and it is a lot of work to do this for each year (20 in total).
My intention was to make a new variable which gives each size group a name. E.g. top 10% largest firms each year should get a variable with the name "Expenditures, 0% size <10%"

Further I make a new dataframe "testtest" where I calculate the different measures, before using the stargazer to present it. This works.

!!EDIT!!
Hi again,

Now I get the error "List object cannot be coerced to type double" when running the code on a new dataset (but it is the same variables as before).

The mutate-step I'm referring to is the "mutate(gs = cut ++" after "rowwise()" in the solution you provided.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5A0YE.png)

[The_code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Op0bp.png)

[The_error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SU6yn.png)

Comment: The usual caveat: you shouldn’t use ‘stargazer’, because [‘stargazer’ is an utterly atrocious package](https://www.reddit.com/r/rstats/comments/6o9v9h/whats_your_favorite_relatively_obscure_r_package/dkgw9q1/). Use ‘[modelsummary](https://cran.r-project.org/package=modelsummary)’ or ‘[texreg](https://cran.r-project.org/package=texreg)’ instead, or *literally anything else*.

Comment: Can you share the output of `dput(test)`? This will provide some data to work from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the quantiles as a nested variable (`size_groups`), and then use `cut()` to create the group sizes (`gs`). Then group by `Year` and `gs` to summarize the indicators you want.

```
test %>% 
  group_by(Year) %>% 
  mutate(size_groups = list(quantile(Firm_size, probs=c(.1,.25,.5,.75,.9)))) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(gs = cut(
    Firm_size,c(-Inf, size_groups, Inf),
    labels = c("Lowest 10%","10%-25%","25%-50%","50%-75%","75%-90%","Highest 10%"))) %>% 
  group_by(Year, gs) %>% 
  summarize(across(Expenditures,.fns = list(mean,median,sd,length)), .groups="drop") %>% 
  rename_all(~c("Year", "Group_Size", "Mean_Exp", "Med_Exp", "SD_Exp","N_Firms"))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 126 x 6
    Year Group_Size  Mean_Exp Med_Exp SD_Exp N_Firms
   <int> <fct>          <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>   <int>
 1  2000 Lowest 10%    20885.  21363.  3710.       3
 2  2000 10%-25%       68127.  69497. 19045.       4
 3  2000 25%-50%       42035.  35371. 30335.       6
 4  2000 50%-75%       36089.  29802. 17724.       6
 5  2000 75%-90%       53319.  54914. 19865.       4
 6  2000 Highest 10%   57756.  49941. 34162.       3
 7  2001 Lowest 10%    55945.  47359. 28283.       3
 8  2001 10%-25%       61825.  70067. 21777.       4
 9  2001 25%-50%       65088.  76340. 29960.       6
10  2001 50%-75%       57444.  53495. 32458.       6
# ... with 116 more rows
```

If you wanted to have an additional column with the yearly mean, you can remove the `.groups="drop"` from the `summarize(across())` line, and then add this final line to the pipeline:

```
mutate(YrMean = sum(Mean_Exp*N_Firms/sum(N_Firms)))
```

Note that this is correctly weighted by the number of Firms in each Group_size, and thus returns the equivalent of doing this with the original data

```
test %>% group_by(Year) %>% summarize(mean(Expenditures))
```

Input Data:

```
set.seed(123)
test = data.frame(
  Firm = replicate(2000, sample(letters,1)),
  Year = sample(2000:2020, 2000, replace=T),
  Firm_size= ceiling(runif(2000,2000,5000)),
  Expenditures = runif(2000, 10000,100000)
) %>% group_by(Firm,Year) %>% slice_head(n=1)
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! Exactly what I needed. Do you then know an easy way of averaging the Mean_Exp for each group size by dividing it by the sum of the six Mean_Exp for the same year?

Comment: You mean the overall mean for each year?  If doing the way you indicate, it would not be correct - it would need to be weighted by the number of firms in each of the strata. See additional comment in answer

Comment: HI! The code you helped me with worked before, but now I get an error when trying to running it on a new dataset. It says "list object cannot be coerced to type double". This happens when I run the mutate-step from your code abow. Any ideas why?

Comment: which mutate step, and can you post an example of the data?

Comment: I tried to edit my question with the new question. Thanks.

Comment: did you forget rowwise()?  I can replicate that error if I remove the rowwise() line.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I added a picture "The_code" which is the code I try to run.

Comment: that code doesn't look right. You are missing a `) %>%` at the of the line that creates the list column, and you have what appears to be extra parentheses at the very end of the last line... Try to carefully step through each line of the code, adding the next line in the pipeline one by one, only after you are satisfied that each line is doing what you want

Comment: Thanks for trying to help! Still get the same error after I try to take the next step after rowwise. I marked the steps that works in blue (in the picture of the code) + a picture of the error (The_error)...